# Importing only a few columns of a csv as a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, large-data

I would like to only import a subset of a csv as a dataframe as it is too large to import the whole thing. Is there a way to do this natively in pandas without having to set up a database like structure?

I have tried only importing a chunk and then concatenating and this is still too large and causes memory error. I have hundreds of columns so manually specifying dtypes could help, but would likely be a major time commitment.

```py
df_chunk = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", chunksize=1e7)
df = pd.concat(df_chunk,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Look at chuncksize in the docs.

Comment: Use `nrows` to specify number of rows you wanna read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv()` with `skiprows` and `nrows`?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the **`skiprows`** and **`nrows`** arguments in the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function to load only a subset of rows from your original dataframe.

For instance:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skiprows = 4, nrows=10)
```

Comment: I need all rows. what about columns?

Comment: For that you can use the *usecols* parameter.